# How can I retrieve the number of currently defined macros?

Tags: tex-core, memory

The following will max-out TeX's memory:

```
% arara: pdftex
\nonstopmode
\input expl3-generic \relax \ExplSyntaxOn

\int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
\int_while_do:nn { \l_tmpa_int < 490000 }
  {
    \cs_new:cn { temp \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int : } { nothing }
    \int_show:N \l_tmpa_int
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
  }
hi
\bye
```

giving the error

> ```
> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=494671].
> ```

after 489008 definitions.  (I'm assuming the remaining ≈5k definitions are from the kernels and formats.)

I assume this number is available in a configuration file somewhere (for the 'wizards' who build TeX), but how can I get this `number of strings=` dynamically from within TeX itself?

---

```sh
sh-3.2$ cat temp-file--8751S9O.tex
hi \bye
sh-3.2$ tex temp-file--8751S9O.tex >/dev/null
sh-3.2$ cat temp-file--8751S9O.log
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=tex 2015.5.24)  26 JUL 2015 09:34
**temp-file--8751S9O.tex
(./temp-file--8751S9O.tex [1] )
Output written on temp-file--8751S9O.dvi (1 page, 208 bytes).
sh-3.2$
```

Comment: after the `\input` line, set "hello world", then `\bye`, and check the stats in the log.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I get no such stats in the log file :( see edit

Comment: @barbarabeeton Besides, the idea is to do some introspection into TeX's state without exiting TeX. *Shouldn't* require two passes, but it might :-/

Comment: Does that compile for you - issues of capacity aside? Or what am I meant to compile it with?

Comment: @cfr Sure, if I take it down by a factor of ten or so. In theory, you should be able to compile with any e-TeX. `pdftex` is what I compile with. I added an arara directive.

Comment: You don't get errors? I mean, it'll carry on regardless with `\nonstopmode` but the errors are still there.

Comment: @cfr Oooh, well that's just because of `\int_show:N`. Remove that line and you won't need `\nonstopmode`, either. Sorry for the confusion. For whatever reason, all of the `_show:N` commands cause 'errors'.

Comment: Actually, if you switch off `\nonstopmode` and ask for help, TeX says that they are *not* errors. Just that wasn't obvious to me with `\nonstopmode` - it just looked like errors scrolling by! Sorry for the confusion & thanks for the clarification.

Comment: forgot you will need `\tracingstats=2`; the report occurs when the job ends.  i suggested doing it once with an essentially empty file, so you'd have a baseline.  (on the system i usually use, this is set as default, so i made a rash assumption.)

Comment: these days you don't need to rebuild tex it's settable in the `texmf.cnf` file,  but you can not get that information from TeX luatex is different, but uses dynamic allocation anyway so you don't run out until you run out of real memory.

Comment: You can access the information without looking in `texmf.cnf` by doing `kpsewhich -var-value max_strings` from the terminal. My machine answers 500000

Comment: @egreg Odd, so does mine – but I guess that raises the separate question of 'where did the other ≈4k strings go?'. Is there no way to retrieve the number of *currently defined* strings from TeX while it's running, though?

Comment: @SeanAllred I guess they're preempted by the format. And no, the information cannot be accessed from a TeX run.

Comment: @egreg do you mind turning this comment into an answer, to remove this item from the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run `pdftex` on

```
\tracingstats=1 \bye
```

the log file will report

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2 strings out of 494671
 95 string characters out of 6148970
 14212 words of memory out of 5000000
 1670 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 14794 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1420 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 1i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

If I run it on

```
\tracingstats=1 \input expl3-generic \relax \ExplSyntaxOn \bye
```

I get

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6750 strings out of 494671
 132558 string characters out of 6148970
 103191 words of memory out of 5000000
 8405 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 14794 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1420 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 22i,0n,31p,10374b,291s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

Thus you have an idea of how much load `expl3` puts on memory, by comparing the empty file with the one with `\input expl3-generic`.

Running your test file with the only addition of `\tracingstats=1` at the beginning, I get the error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=494671].
```

and the log file shows

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 494671 strings out of 494671
 5388582 string characters out of 6148970
 4493699 words of memory out of 5000000
 496323 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 14794 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1420 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,31p,10361b,291s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

Memory would be exhausted earlier if the replacement text in the `\cs_new:cn` instruction is longer.

The information about memory is not available during a TeX run. This limitation is not in LuaTeX, see section 4.13 of the manual about the `status` library.